# dynamic svg path in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, turtle-graphics

I’m working on a d3.js implementation of turtle graphics. Basically when we give the turtle instructions to draw or move, it translates those instructions to  a form acceptable by a svg path object for its "d" attribute.

I'd like the user be able to give the turtle instructions (either at the javascript console or, eventually, with buttons) and have the path on the svg canvas update dynamically. Right now I can do this, but the `transition()` isn't working out. I.e. no matter what I set `duration()` to for the transition, it updates instantaneously. Maybe this has something to do with the fact that I am not binding the instructions as data to the path element?

I have a Turtle constructor, and a Vector2D constructor, defined below:

```
<body>
<script src="path_to_D3"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 800);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(-1000, 1000).range(0, 800)
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(-1000, 1000).range(0, 800)

// Here's where I am having an issue with binding data. 

var path = svg.append("path").attr("stroke", "red").attr("fill", "none");

// Proposed alternative: var path = d3.select(".turtlePath").data("");
//                           path.enter().append("path").attr("class", "turtlePath")
//                             .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
//           

function Vector2D(x, y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y

  this.add = function(other) {
    return new Vector2D(x + other.x, y + other.y)
  }

  this.scaleBy(factor) {
    return new Vector2D(x * factor, y * factor)
  }
}


functionTurtle() {
  var position = new Vector2D(0, 0)
  var angle = 0;
  var pathInstruct = “M” + x(0) + “, “ + y(0) + “ “;
  var moveDist = 100;
  this.penDown = false;



  this.goForward = function() {
    var xAdd = Math.cos(angle);
    var yAdd = Math.sin(angle);
    position = position.add(new Vector2D(xAdd, yAdd).scaleBy(moveDist));

    // Here is the crucial bit. 
    var newInstruct = "";
    if (penDown) {
      newInstruct = "L" + x(position.x) + ", " + y(position.y) + " ";
    } else {
      newInstruct = "m" + x(position.x) + ", " + y(position.y) + " ";
    }
    pathInstruct += newInstruct;

    // Here's where I'd like the transition to occur. 
    path.attr("d", pathInstruct);
    // Proposed: path.data(pathInstruct).transition().duration(500)
    //               .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
  }

}   
</script>
</body>
```

Then I can give the turtle commands and have them show up on the canvas:

```
var t = new Turtle()
t.penDown = true;
t.goForward();
t.goForward();
t.penDown = false;
```

These commands for the turtle result in a simple horizontal line.  But I'd like for the path to update dynamically rather than instantaneously, as in Mike Bostock's [post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/).  Do I need to bind the path instructions to the path element as data?

Comment: I don't see any transitions in your code. Where are you adding those?

Comment: I'll edit to show where they were. Code breaks when I try to add them which is why they were initially ommitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the transition -- it's caused by the `.data()` call at both your initialization and update steps.

The parameter you pass to `.data()` *must* be an array of data values, one for each element in the selection, even if you only have one element and therefore one data value.

To solve it, you have two options:

1. Create an ad-hoc array by wrapping your data value in brackets when you call the method:

   ```
   path.data([pathInstruct]).transition().duration(500)
             .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
   ```
2. Use the `.datum()` method, which accepts a single data value and attaches it to every element in the selection:

   ```
   path.datum(pathInstruct).transition().duration(500)
             .attr("d", function(d) { return d; });
   ```

Note that the `.datum()` method does not create an `enter()` or `exit()` selection; you would have to create the path element first before setting data with `.datum()`.